# NameError: name 'num_dims' is not defined が発生してしまう

Tags: python, python3, numpy

下記のサイトに掲載されていたプログラムを実行するとエラーが出てしまいます。
どのようにすれば解決できるでしょうか。

[OCRをpythonで自作する方法【機械学習】](https://ebi-works.com/ocr-python/)

**プログラム**

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 

# 手書き画像の読み込みとimageオブジェクトの作成
img = Image.open('a.png')
width, height = img.size
img2 = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))

 # getpixel((x,y))で左からx番目,上からy番目のピクセルの色を取得し、img_pixelsに追加する
img_pixels = []
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        img_pixels.append(img.getpixel((x,y)))

# データの規格化
img_pixels_norm = []
for i in range(8*16):
    p = img_pixels[i][0]
    if p == 0:
        img_pixels_norm.append(1.)
    else:
        img_pixels_norm.append(0.)

img_pixels_norm = np.array( img_pixels_norm).reshape(-1, num_dims)

#結果表示
predicted = nn.sim( img_pixels_norm) 
print('結果:', orig_labels[np.argmax(predicted)])
```

**エラー内容**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a6b6226034ac> in <module>
     22         img_pixels_norm.append(0.)
     23 
---> 24 img_pixels_norm = np.array( img_pixels_norm).reshape(-1, num_dims)
     25 
     26 #結果表示

NameError: name 'num_dims' is not defined
```

Comment: 該当のページのどのソースにも`num_dims`は使われてはいても定義はされていないようですので、記事の作者に問い合わせてみてはどうでしょう？ コメントを入れることも出来るようですし。

Comment: わかりました。ご意見ありがとうございます。

Comment: 元記事へのQ&Aで上手く修正され、対象のパラメータは`8*16`という具体的な数値に変更されました。